# jQuery Resize Plugin apply to <a>

Tags: jquery, image, jquery-plugins, resize, gallery

I'm usign jQuery resize plugin [Plugin here](https://github.com/adeelejaz/jquery-image-resize), it work's as it should on images.

But I'm trying to apply it to the gallery [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/example-2.html)

The problem is that the main image is wraped in `<a>` and when I add a class to the `<a>` tag the resize don't work.

Any suggestions?

Here is my markup:

```
<li>
<a class="thumb resize2" name="imagen1" href="images/400x400-1.jpg" title="imagen1">
<img class="resize1" src="images/400x400-1.jpg" alt="Title #0" />
</a>
</li>
<li>
<a class="thumb resize2" name="drop" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2404/2538171134_2f77bc00d9.jpg" title="Title #1">
<img class="resize1" src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2404/2538171134_2f77bc00d9_s.jpg" alt="Title #1" />
</a>
<div class="caption">
Any html can be placed here ...
</div>
</li>
```

Here's the script:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( ".resize1" ).aeImageResize({ height: 70, width: 70 });
    $( ".resize2" ).aeImageResize({ height: 10, width: 10 });
});
</script>
```

The resize script is perfect, but I need it to funcion on `<a>`

P.D. I'm begginer in jQuery and scripting in general.

UPDATE:
Here is screenshot how it is shown in browser:
[image: Screen shot of the code]

Here is a fraction from galleriffic.js file

```
var newSlide = this.$imageContainer
                    .append('<span class="image-wrapper current"><a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#'+this.data[nextIndex].hash+'" title="'+imageData.title+'">&nbsp;</a></span>')
                    .find('span.current').css('opacity', '0');

                newSlide.find('a')
                    .append(imageData.image)
                    .click(function(e) {
                        gallery.clickHandler(e, this);
                    });
```

It ads advance-link class.

The question is: How can I add a class to the image in advance class container? I hope I've expressed myself correctly.

Thank you,

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting the current displayed image can be achieved like this (there is only one image in the slideshow at a given time):

```
$("div#slideshow img")
```

But in order to change the gallery "main" image's size, you need to set the width and height also for the following elements:

```
$("div#slideshow a.advance-link")
// and also the parent element of $("div#slideshow") which I can't see in the screenshot you attached.
```

Adding "resize" functionality to the < a > elements the gallery is built from will not affect the gallery image.