# Copy url and paste it in src

Tags: jquery, html, image, copy, clone

I'm trying to modify a gallery, so I wouldn't have to paste the link several times.

Can anyone advice the best method to copy the link from `a href` to the image `src`??

Here is my markup:

```
<li>
<a class="thumb resize2" id="img2" name="drop" href="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2404/2538171134_2f77bc00d9.jpg" title="Title #1">
   <img class="resize1" id="img2-2" src="" alt="Title #1" />
</a>
<div class="caption">
   Any html can be placed here ...
</div>
</li>
```

and is it posible to make a variable from the li `#img2` and `img2-2`

For example: I have 10 images places in `li` and the link to the image is placed only onces, so the script will run through all li's and copy and paste the links in particular `li`? Did I make myself clear what I want to achieve?

I'm trying to achieve this using jQuery.

Thanks guys,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('li a.thumb').each(function(){
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $(this).find('img').attr('src',href);
});
```

Comment: Perfect, worked. Maybe you can help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16275824/jquery-resize-plugin-apply-to-a